# Issue when joining serf nodes located in different Docker containers

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, consul

*Context: Host is AWS-EC2 / Ubuntu 14.04.5 with Docker version 17.05.0-ce. Containers are built from publicly available repo image `cbhihe/serf-alpine-bash`. All containers are located on the same EC2 instance and share the same default bridge network with net-interface "docker0".*

Trying to join nodes serfDC1 (id d4fd90692e18) and serfDC2 (id 6353e7f6134d), by passing cmds from the host's shell:

```
$ docker exec serfDC1 serf agent -node=Node1 -bind=0.0.0.0:7946
==> Starting Serf agent…
==> Starting Serf agent RPC...
==> Serf agent running!
         Node name: 'd4fd90692e18'
         Bind addr: '0.0.0.0:7946'
          RPC addr: '127.0.0.1:7373'
         Encrypted: false
          Snapshot: false
           Profile: lan
==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
    2017/06/04 00:01:10 [INFO] agent: Serf agent starting
    2017/06/04 00:01:10 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: d4fd90692e18 127.0.0.1
    2017/06/04 00:01:11 [INFO] agent: Received event: member-join
    ^C
```

After discovering Node1's container's IP=172.17.0.4, I can issue the `serf agent -join` cmd to Node2:

```
$ docker exec serfDC2 serf agent -node=Node2 -join=172.17.0.4
==> Starting Serf agent...
==> Starting Serf agent RPC...
==> Serf agent running!
         Node name: '6353e7f6134d'
         Bind addr: '0.0.0.0:7946'
          RPC addr: '127.0.0.1:7373'
         Encrypted: false
          Snapshot: false
           Profile: lan
==> Joining cluster...(replay: false)
    Join completed. Synced with 1 initial agents
==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
    2017/06/04 00:18:35 [INFO] agent: Serf agent starting
    2017/06/04 00:18:35 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 6353e7f6134d 127.0.0.1
    2017/06/04 00:18:35 [INFO] agent: joining: [172.17.0.4] replay: false
    2017/06/04 00:18:35 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: d4fd90692e18 127.0.0.1
    2017/06/04 00:18:35 [INFO] agent: joined: 1 nodes
    2017/06/04 00:18:36 [WARN] memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node 'd4fd90692e18' from=127.0.0.1:7946
    2017/06/04 00:18:36 [INFO] agent: Received event: member-join
    2017/06/04 00:18:37 [WARN] memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node d4fd90692e18 from=127.0.0.1:34876
    2017/06/04 00:18:37 [ERR] memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: EOF
    2017/06/04 00:18:37 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect d4fd90692e18 has failed, no acks received
    2017/06/04 00:18:38 [WARN] memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node 'd4fd90692e18' from=127.0.0.1:7946
    2017/06/04 00:18:39 [WARN] memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node d4fd90692e18 from=127.0.0.1:34879
    2017/06/04 00:18:39 [ERR] memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: EOF
    2017/06/04 00:18:40 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect d4fd90692e18 has failed, no acks received
    2017/06/04 00:18:41 [WARN] memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node 'd4fd90692e18' from=127.0.0.1:7946
    2017/06/04 00:18:42 [WARN] memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node d4fd90692e18 from=127.0.0.1:34881
    2017/06/04 00:18:42 [ERR] memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: EOF
    2017/06/04 00:18:42 [INFO] memberlist: Marking d4fd90692e18 as failed, suspect timeout reached (0 peer confirmations)
    2017/06/04 00:18:42 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: d4fd90692e18 127.0.0.1
    2017/06/04 00:18:43 [INFO] agent: Received event: member-failed
    2017/06/04 00:18:44 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect d4fd90692e18 has failed, no acks received
    2017/06/04 00:19:05 [INFO] serf: attempting reconnect to d4fd90692e18 127.0.0.1:7946
   ^C
```

Resulted in failure to join as shown by:

```
$ docker exec serfDC2 serf members
6353e7f6134d  127.0.0.1:7946  alive
d4fd90692e18  127.0.0.1:7946  failed  
$ docker exec serfDC1 serf members
d4fd90692e18  127.0.0.1:7946  alive 
6353e7f6134d  127.0.0.1:7946  failed
```

I have been at this for quite some time now and am at my wit's end as to where I should turn. Hashicorp's and Docker's documentation do not seem to cover this aspect of the initial handshake between two serf agents in different containers.

***Could somebody show me where I took a wrong turn ?*** Any answer would be great, really. Tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serf nodes need to 'announce' themselves with a routable address. In your case they are telling to each other: 'hi, I'm localhost:...', so each one tries to answer to localhost, which is something wrong because each container has its own localhost.

There is an option to configure the agent to use the `eth0` ip to advertise to the others nodes in the network: `-iface`. Then you need to discard the `-bind` option. Those ports are default so there is no need to customize.

So, for the node1:

```
serf agent -node=Node1 -iface=eth0
```

And for the node2:

```
serf agent -node=Node2 -join=172.17.0.2 -iface=eth0
```

From [docs](https://www.serf.io/docs/agent/options.html):

> -iface - This flag can be used to provide a binding interface. It can be used instead of -bind if the interface is known but not the address.

It's working properly for me:

Node1:

```
==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2017/06/04 01:56:40 [INFO] agent: Serf agent starting
    2017/06/04 01:56:40 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: Node1 172.17.0.2
    2017/06/04 01:56:41 [INFO] agent: Received event: member-join
    2017/06/04 01:57:02 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: Node2 172.17.0.3
    2017/06/04 01:57:03 [INFO] agent: Received event: member-join
```

Node2:

```
==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2017/06/04 01:57:02 [INFO] agent: Serf agent starting
    2017/06/04 01:57:02 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: Node2 172.17.0.3
    2017/06/04 01:57:02 [INFO] agent: joining: [172.17.0.2] replay: false
    2017/06/04 01:57:02 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: Node1 172.17.0.2
    2017/06/04 01:57:02 [INFO] agent: joined: 1 nodes
    2017/06/04 01:57:03 [INFO] agent: Received event: member-join
```

---

**Edit:**

In the case that each container is in its own VM (EC2 instance), as each instance has its own docker network and not interconnected, you have to provide the EC2 instance IP and expose the corresponding ports. Use [`-advertise`](https://www.serf.io/docs/agent/options.html#advertise)

> -advertise - The advertise flag is used to change the address that we advertise to other nodes in the cluster.

Node1:

```
serf agent -node=Node1 -iface=eth0 -advertise=INSTANCE_IP
```

Node2:

```
serf agent -node=Node2 -join=NODE1_INSTANCE_IP -iface=eth0
```

And remember to **expose** the serf port in `docker run`

```
docker run -p 7946:7946 (...rest of the command...)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Tx !  It turns out I had tried something extremely similar, but the hard (read "wrong") way a few days ago, building a new EC2 instance-wide net-interface (NI) and overlooking the obvious one because I wanted to use separate NIs for world<=>instance traffic and for inter-container traffic........... So, in the case of a cluster of dockerized serf nodes distributed over several EC2 instances (each with its own `eth0` NI), how do you disambiguate `eth0` to connect the various dockerized serf nodes _**across instances**_ ?

Comment: Always welcome! You need to provide the EC2 eth0 instance ip instead of the docker network ip (172.17...), because each EC2 instance virtualize its own Docker network so they are independent and not inter-connected. Let see my **Edit:** part in this answer