# "Failed to resolve IP"; "Lookup error" in bash script when joining dockerized serf agents

Tags: bash, docker, ip-address, lookup

*[Context: Host is AWS-EC2 / Ubuntu 14.04.5 with Docker version 17.05.0-ce. Containers are built from publicly available repo image cbhihe/serf-alpine-bash. Containers are located on the same EC2 instance and share the same default bridge network as well as the instance's eth0 interface.]*

This question builds on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349963/issue-when-joining-serf-nodes-located-in-different-docker-containers) to a different issue.

Working with two running `docker` containers, each with a live `serf` agent in it, I want to form a two node serf cluster from an unattended bash script, executing on the host where the two containers run.

For one serf agent in container "DC2" to join another in container "DC1" with private IP 172.17.0.2,  my script looks like:

```
docker run -d --name DC1 --rm cbhihe/serf-alpine-bash agent -node=NODE1 -iface=eth0
docker run -d --name DC2 --rm cbhihe/serf-alpine-bash agent -node=NODE2 -iface=eth0
docker exec -d DC2 serf join 172.17.0.2
```

The two first line produce the expected result, i.e. 2 running containers. The third line seem to fail:

- either silently, when using the *detached* switch,
- or with the following error in the absence of such switch.

  Error joining the cluster: 1 error(s) occurred:
  Failed to resolve 172.17.0.2 : lookup 172.17.0.2 : invalid domain name

Either way joining does not occur. 
Doing exactly the same thing from console works flawlessly.

I looked at importing the host's environment in my script's bash shebang context. Was not successsful. Pointers are welcome. Tx

Comment: Maybe some dependency with the shell? Try `docker exec DC2 bash -c 'serf join 172.17.0.2'`

Comment: @Robert, It works fine in my use case with:  `docker exec "$cont_id"  bash -c 'serf join '"$join_IP"`  Can you make it an answer, maybe padding it with a short explanation of `bash -c` environment particulars for future readers ? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information in your question, I think that there could be a dependency to the shell, that sets environment variables.

Try executing serf launched by bash. Something like this:

```
docker exec "$cont_id" bash -c 'serf join '"$join_IP"
```